# Way to add an object in a specific position of a list array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I want to add an animal (the hare) in the array list by checking
if the elephant I add it in front of the elephant if not I add it in front of the lion last element of my list
how can I do, because there with what I make it does not work

```
data class Animal (val name:String)
val animals = arrayListOf<Animal>()
animals.addAll(listOf(Animal("Lion"), Animal("Elephant"), Animal("Tiger")))
if(animals.filter { it.name.contains("n") }) {
animals.add(Animal("hare"))
}
println(animals)
```

how can i do it ?

Comment: You're trying to do too much with that `name.contains("n")` trick - there are too many situations where it will give the wrong result. You need to do like in Ahmet's answer -separate checks with something like `if`/`else if`, so you can look for *Elephant* and do something, **otherwise** look for *Lion* and do something else, etc

Comment: Hi @cactustictacs, i didn't see Ahmet's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the other answerer deleted their post, here's an example:

```
data class Animal(val name: String)

fun main() {
    // just create a MutableList like this - it's the Kotlin way of doing things
    val animals = mutableListOf(Animal("Lion"), Animal("Elephant"), Animal("Tiger"))

    // get the index of the first element that matches this predicate (true/false check)
    val elephantIndex = animals.indexOfFirst { it.name == "Elephant" }
    
    // get the index of the LAST element that has the name "Lion"
    val lionIndex = animals.indexOfLast { it.name == "Lion" }

    // if nothing matched, the index will be -1 
    if (elephantIndex >= 0) {
        // adding at the index of the matching element inserts the new item
        // at that position, sliding the remaining items "up" a position
        animals.add(elephantIndex, Animal("Hare"))
    } else if (lionIndex >= 0) {
        // the above check only happens if elephantIndex WASN'T >= 0,
        // i.e. if we didn't find "Elephant". So now we've found a "Lion"
        animals.add(lionIndex, Animal("Hare"))
    } else {
        // this is your fallback, default case - if neither of the above cases
        // matched, you can do something else here. Only one of these if/else blocks
        // will be run! And with an 'else', you guarantee that one will ALWAYS run
    }

    println(animals)
}
```

You could be more elegant about this, but it's just an example of how the logic basically works. Also I'm not exactly sure what you meant about *"add it in front of the lion last element of my list"* - this shows you how to look for the *first* elephant and *last* lion, but you can change that. If you want to add to the end of the list when there are no elephants OR lions, put it in the `else` block